# How to create random animated random integer 0-9 for a clicking game

Tags: javascript, html

New to javascript and html,wanted to write a code that has 3 labels and they will change at regular intervals to random numbers (0-9)for each label. user keys in a number, and everytime the number is clicked, counter score will increase ++. If any other numbers are clicked, the counter would decrease. 
Closest example I can find shows a similar game but using images instead integer labels.

```js
var totalscore = 0;
    var counter = 0;
    var Schedule;
    
    function happyFish() {
      totalscore++;
      var happyclickSpan = document.getElementById("score");
      happyclickSpan.innerHTML = totalscore;
      counter = counter + 1;
      if (counter == 10) {
        clearInterval(Schedule);
        var finalwords = document.getElementById("d");
        finalwords.innerHTML = "Your Score:" + counter + " Game Over. You Win!";
      }
    
    }
    
    function sadFish() {
      totalscore--;
      var sadclickSpan = document.getElementById("score");
      sadclickSpan.innerHTML = totalscore;
      counter = counter - 1;
      if (counter == -10) {
        clearInterval(Schedule);
        var finalwords = document.getElementById("d");
        finalwords.innerHTML = "Your Score:" + counter + " Game Over. You Lose!";
      }
    }
    
    function StartAnimation() {
      counter = 0;
      totalscore = 0;
      var initialWords = document.getElementById("d");
        initialWords.innerHTML = "Your Score: <span id=\"score\">0</span>";
    
      Schedule = setInterval(animationfunction, 500);
    }
    
    function animationfunction() {
      var fish_img = document.getElementById("happy_fish");
      var f_img = document.getElementById("sad_fish");
    
      fish_img.classList.toggle('off');
      f_img.classList.toggle('off');
    }
```

```html
    <button onClick="StartAnimation()">Start Animation</button>
    <br>
    <img src="triangle.png" alt="happy" id="1" onClick="happyFish()">
    <img src="circle.png" alt="sad" id="sad_fish" class="off" onClick="sadFish()">
    <br>
    <h1 id="d">
      Your Score: <span id="score">0</span>
    </h1>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a bit late but yea, posting my final code here for this question in the hopes it will help other students understand

the html portion

```
<button onClick="startGame()">Start Game</button>
<button onClick="stopGame()">Stop Game</button>
</br>
<div>
    <p id="chosenNumber" style="font-size: 50px"></p>
</div>
<div>
    <p id="score" style="font-size:50px"></p>
</div>
<div>
<table border="0" width="100%">
    <td width="33.3%" height="250" style="font-size:300px" align="center">
    <p style="color:red" id="numberLeft" onclick="scoreGiver()"></p>
    </td>
    <td width="33.3%" style="font-size:300px" align="center">
    <p style="color:orange" id="numberMid" onclick="scoreGiver()"></p>
    </td>
    <td width="33.3%" style="font-size:300px" align="center">
    <p style="color:blue" id="numberRight" onclick="scoreGiver()"></p>
    </td>
</table>
</div>
<p>
```

and the js portion

```
<script>
var totalscore = 0;
var counter = 0;
var schedule;



function startGame()
    {
        totalScore = 0;
        number = prompt("Please choose an integer between 0 and 9");
        document.getElementById("chosenNumber").innerHTML = "Your chosen number is: " + number; 
        document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Your score so far: " + totalScore;    


        schedule = setInterval(randomNumbers,1000);
    }
    function stopGame()
    {
        clearInterval(schedule);
    }
    function randomNumbers()
    {
        random1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 0);
        random2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 0);
        random3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 0);
        document.getElementById("numberLeft").innerHTML = random1;  
        document.getElementById("numberMid").innerHTML = random2;   
        document.getElementById("numberRight").innerHTML = random3; 
    }
    function scoreGiver()
    {
        if ((number == random1) || (number == random2) || (number == random3))
        {
            totalscore++;
            document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Your score so far: " + totalscore;    
        }
        else
        {
            totalscore--;
            document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Your score so far: " + totalscore;    
        }

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand completely what do you want, but I fixed some bugs in your code:

- The happy image should have the ID `happy_fish`
- To let toggling `off` class take effect, I created an `off` class, hiding the element.

Try this:

```js
var totalscore = 0;
    var counter = 0;
    var Schedule;
    
    function happyFish() {
      totalscore++;
      var happyclickSpan = document.getElementById("score");
      happyclickSpan.innerHTML = totalscore;
      counter = counter + 1;
      if (counter == 10) {
        clearInterval(Schedule);
        var finalwords = document.getElementById("d");
        finalwords.innerHTML = "Your Score:" + counter + " Game Over. You Win!";
      }
    
    }
    
    function sadFish() {
      totalscore--;
      var sadclickSpan = document.getElementById("score");
      sadclickSpan.innerHTML = totalscore;
      counter = counter - 1;
      if (counter == -10) {
        clearInterval(Schedule);
        var finalwords = document.getElementById("d");
        finalwords.innerHTML = "Your Score:" + counter + " Game Over. You Lose!";
      }
    }
    
    function StartAnimation() {
      counter = 0;
      totalscore = 0;
      var initialWords = document.getElementById("d");
        initialWords.innerHTML = "Your Score: <span id=\"score\">0</span>";
    
      Schedule = setInterval(animationfunction, 500);
    }
    
    function animationfunction() {
      var fish_img = document.getElementById("happy_fish");
      var f_img = document.getElementById("sad_fish");
    
      fish_img.classList.toggle('off');
      f_img.classList.toggle('off');
    }
```

```css
.off{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="StartAnimation()">Start Animation</button>
    <br>
    <img src="triangle.png" alt="happy" id="happy_fish" onClick="happyFish()">
    <img src="circle.png" alt="sad" id="sad_fish" class="off" onClick="sadFish()">
    <br>
    <h1 id="d">
      Your Score: <span id="score">0</span>
    </h1>
```

Comment: that doesn't help at all though and shouldn't be an answer.

Comment: @DasSaffe What's the problem with that?

Comment: thats not "his" code, he said thats the closest he found. Also this is still using images, what he doesn't want.